# Apparmor profile for executing untrusted binaries for online judge

Tags: linux, sandbox, apparmor

I am writing an online judge so I need to sandbox execution of untrusted binaries for judging and for that, I am using apparmor. Here's my current simple profile:

```
#include <tunables/global>

profile bin_jail {
  deny /** rwkx,
}
```

The programs are compiled statically so they don't need to access any dynamically linked libraries. Should I add something more? will this deny access to literally every possible bad thing a program can do? Note that I am also enforcing time and memory constraints through `ulimit` separately.

Comment: Welcome to the community. You should clarify your goal. Online Judge is a programming competition I would assume?

Comment: Yeah it basically just checks if a solution is correct by comparing its output to a file. My question is actually about running untrusted binaries using apparmor. The online judge part is not really important and was just for giving context.